# SpringBoot disabling DataSourceAutoconfigure error while running Junit Tests

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test, spring-autoconfiguration

I have Springboot application works fine which connects to the Datasource. For Junit I have disabled the Autoconfigure of DataSource by excluding the DatasourceAutoConfiguration, DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration classes to avoid SpringBoot Autoconfiguring the DataSource.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
<dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
<dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>8.2.2.jre8</version>
<dependency>
```

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"com.basepackage"})
public class SampleClass{
  psvm(){
  SpringApplication.run(SampleClass.class,args);
}
}
```

JuniTestClass

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=SampleClass.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SampleControllerTest {
  @MockBean
  private SampleService service;

  @Test
  public void fetchUsers() {
    Mockito.when(service.retrieveUsers().thenReturn(new SampleResponse());
}
```

}

On mvn test, the Test scripts are run but failing, because SampleRepository bean is not Autoconfigured (might be because of  exclusion of the Datasource and HibernateJpa autoconfig classes) by Springboot

Error

```
Caused by UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name ServiceDAOImpl, nested exception No qualifying bean of type com.basepackage.repository.SampleRepository' : expected atleast 1 bean which qualifies ...................
```

If I remove the AutoConfig Exclusion, the Junit tests works fine in local workspace which configures Datasource (though with JUnit connectivity to DB should not be established). The issue is I am setting up devops pipeline and during "Maven Test", SpringBoot autoconfigures the DataSource and the connectivity to Jenkins to DB fails.

I would like to disable the Autoconfig during Junit - Maven Test and on actual SpringBoot jar build, the autoconfiguration should be enabled.

Can someone please let me know how to achieve this with Annotations?

Answer (score 6):

Disabling auto-configuration for your database is one thing, but your application classes rely on (I guess) JPA repositories from Spring Data (they inject it using `@Autowired`) to work.

If you now disable auto-configuration for your database, your JPA repositories can't be bootstrapped by Spring Data and hence your service classes fail on startup as they require an available instance: `... expected at least 1 bean which qualifies`.

I guess you have three choices to solve this:

1. Use [Testcontainers](https://rieckpil.de/howto-write-spring-boot-integration-tests-with-a-real-database/) to provide a *real* database during your tests and enable auto-configuration of the data related parts again. This would be the *best* solution as you can test your application with the same database you use in production.
2. Keep disabling auto-configuration, but provide a *manual* datasource configuration for your tests:

```
@SpringBootTest
class ApplicationIntegrationTest {

  @TestConfiguration
  public static class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
      return DataSourceBuilder
        .create()
        .password("YOUR PASSWORD")
        .url("YOUR MSSQL URL")
        .username("YOUR USERNAME")
        .build();
    }
  }
}
```

3. Use `@MockBean` for all your repositories. This would allow you to completetly work without any database, but you would have to define any interaction with your repositories for yourself using Mockito:

```
@SpringBootTest
class SpringBootStackoverflowApplicationTests {

  @MockBean
  private SampleRepository sampleRepository;
  
  @MockBean
  private OtherRepository otherRepository;
  
  // your tests
}
```